# What is the best way to write a switch statement to return an image depending on a number without repeating to much code?

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a switch statement that returns an image based on the case number. I have 8 images of water droplets that start off as an empty droplet(drop_empty) and when the number increases from 1...6 and so on as shown in my code I want to change the images. For the 8 images as shown in the screenshot, I have each one set in an @IBOutlet and in an array in order to choose what image get's assigned to what. I do feel that I'm repeating my self way too much and am hoping to find a better solution to shorten my repetition.
Hopefully, my code makes more sense.

[image]

```
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage1: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage2: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage3: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage4: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage5: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage6: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage7: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var waterDropImage8: UIImageView!
    
    // Example function name that I would call
    func showDroplets() {
        dropletImageManager(waterPercentage: percentage, droplet: [waterDropImage1, waterDropImage2, waterDropImage3, waterDropImage4, waterDropImage5, waterDropImage6, waterDropImage7, waterDropImage8])
     }

    func dropletImageManager(waterPercentage: Int, droplet: [UIImageView]) {
        switch waterPercentage {
        case 0:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_empty")
        case 1...6:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_half")
        case 7...12:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
        case 13...18:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_half")
        case 19...25:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
        case 26...31:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_empty")
        case 32...38:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
        case 39...45:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_half")
        case 46...52:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_half")
        case 53...59:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
        case 60...66:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[5].image = UIImage(named: "drop_half")
        case 67...73:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[5].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
        case 74...78:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[5].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[6].image = UIImage(named: "drop_half")
        case 79...85:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[5].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[6].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
        case 86...92:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[5].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[6].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[7].image = UIImage(named: "drop_half")
        case 93...100:
            droplet[0].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[1].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[2].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[3].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[4].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[5].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[6].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
            droplet[7].image = UIImage(named: "drop_full")
        default:
            print("Error")
        }
```

Comment: If this has helped, please consider accepting my answer. If you don't know what this means, take a read at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I understand your answer but it’s not what I’m looking for. Your answer does help in some ways so I’ll accept your answer. I might have not explained my question correctly.

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this don't be afraid to edit your question or even open another thread, I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll do better if you make a calculation of how much droplets you can fill with the water amount you have. I'm not proficient with swift so I'll write it in a "pseudo-language", but I guess you'll be able to understand it.

Let's say it takes 12.5% to fill each droplet (100 / 8).

```c
float renderDroplets(int waterAmounnt) {
    int numOfDroplets = int(waterAmount / 12.5)
    renderFullDroplets(numOfDroplets)

    float remainingWater = int(waterAmount % 12.5)
    if (remainingWater >= 6.5) {
        renderHalfDroplet();
    } else {
        renderEmptyDroplet();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.